# Toggle script: change from jQuery to "normal javascript" code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been using a toggle script (open/close text container when clicking on a certain link) for a website that uses jQuery. In order to clean up the website I want to get rid of jQuery completely but have some problems converting the existing jQuery code into "normal javascript".

Here is the existing code:

```
jQuery(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle_container").hide();
    $("h4.trigger").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("normal");
        return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
});
});
});
```

Which corresponds to this HTML source code:

```
<h4 class="trigger toggle-transparent "><a href="#">Click to show more</a></h3><div class="toggle_container ">
Hidden Text
</div>
```

I've tried the following code which doesn't give me an error but just doesn't do anything when clicking on the trigger:

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll('h4.trigger');
for(var i=0; i < el.length; i++){
    el[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        this.classList.toggle("active").nextSibling.classList.toggle("toggle_container-active");
    }.bind(this));
}
```

The only thing I really need for the code is: clicking on the class "trigger" should toggle some HTML class "active" to both the trigger element as well as the toggle_container element. The rest I'm able to change with just CSS.

The hard part of the code is that it should work for multiple toggle areas on one page separately (therefore using a class, not an id).

Any idea where my code has a problem or any (completely) different suggestions?

I have very limited experience with javascript/jQuery and feel more at home with HTML/CSS.

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: You can't chain method calls like that in plain JS, as you do in jQuery. You need to separate the `classList.toggle` calls

Answer (score 0):

The `this.classList.toggle("active")` doesn't return the element back again, but just a boolean to inform if the action was successful. Chaining happens only in jQuery and not in vanilla JavaScript.

```
this.classList.toggle("active").nextSibling.classList.toggle("toggle_container-active");
```

You should be using something like this instead of the above:

```
this.classList.toggle("active");
this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("toggle_container-active");
```

Comment: Ah, thank you for this remark.
Unfortunately it still doesn't work but now gives me the following error message: "TypeError: this.classList is undefined".

I've never really learned javascript yet but I'm just scraping together what I can find on the internet. Any idea what might be wrong with the rest of the code?

Comment: @Patrick I am happy to help you if you can create a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com) with a working thing and also tell me what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the offer. I created a JSBin as you asked with the HTML, CSS and JS (<- still as jQuery) code from my website: https://jsbin.com/naferebela/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Unfortunately the console shows an undefined error message which is not very helpful.

Please check my website to see how it's supposed to work: www.wowtamins.de/test/

Thank you,
Patrick

Comment: @Patrick It says `jQuery is not defined` - We need to include jQuery. I have done it. Look at it now: https://jsbin.com/mayiqisuxa/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Ah, right. It was my first time using JSBin. Now it does exactly what it's supposed to do: clicking on the trigger will open the hidden content container. Clicking on the trigger again will close it. Now without changing anything in HTML and CSS I tried to change the jQuery code to "just javascript": https://jsbin.com/juwecihupo/edit?html,css,js,console,output Unfortunately both lines that start with "this." give me an undefined error message. Are you able to see the root of the problem? As I said: the idea of the code can be changed completely if necessary as long as it works in the end.